# How to make sure Gitlab Pipeline will run only on merge and not on tags?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab job that I want to run only when the feature branch gets merged into the main branch and never runs on tags.

I tried with `except` but `rules` and `except` keywords don't like each other.

```
delete-unstable-tags-on-merge:
stage: cleanup
script:
- // Script to delete tags
rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /Merge.+branch\s(.*)\sinto(.*)/'
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG !~ "/^$/"'
tags:
- linux
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your rule so that your job does not run on a tag.

To do this I normally add a check to see if the pipeline was trigger via a tag and then set the `when` keyword to never.

I personally like to order my rules from most restrictive being on top to least restrictive being at the bottom.

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    when: never
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /Merge.+branch\s(.*)\sinto(.*)/
```